# MVC: sorting displayed view by a specific table.column

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC.
Following this [asp net tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

The course class has a PK of courseID.  Strictly following the tutorial the courses are always displayed (for Edit/index etc.) by the ascending courseID.

I'm ready to take some baby steps and go off-tutorial:  Thought I'd start with  Index.cshtml that displays each instructor's courses but instead of in courseID order, in Title order (ie Algebra, Calculus, Macroeo, Microeco etc.)

In the index.view the courses are represented as part of the instructors' model:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Instructors)
     foreach (var course in item.Courses)
```

That seems to tell me I should be able to do this in the model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
```

and if not there then somehow using

```
item.Courses.OrderBy()
```

but OrderBy wants an overload, nothing I give it works.  I sussed out that it probably wants something like:

```
OrderBy(c => c.Title)
```

but where can I do this?  I'm sure its just one kick in the pants I need in the right direction.  Anyone wanna take a shot?

not totally bewildered yet, thanks folks

Comment: Sorry for being so direct, but you're definitely not ready to take some baby steps. The sorting can be done either in your Controller or in the View, depending on how complex it is, but not in the Model for sure. In this particular case, it really doesn't matter whether you do it in the Controller or in the View.

Comment: So I had the right ideas? just didn't get the puzzle pieces quite right. Thanks!